# How can change the logo of Tkinter GUI screen

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I was trying to change the Logo of my Python Tkinter GUI, as right now it is displayed as "Tk" at top left corner. Can somebody please tell me how to change this and please write something custom names?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just do this with your `root` :

```
root.wm_iconbitmap('myicon.ico')
```

Here is a small example:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.wm_iconbitmap('myicon.ico')
root.wm_title('Title')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi @Ajain if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much but I am stuck with following error TclError: bitmap "c:/Proj/Images/MyPic1.bmp" not defined

Comment: Accroding to [this](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/wm.htm#M18) & [this](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3177) only `.ico` or `.icr` files are supported.

Comment: glad to be of some help :)